# Travis VS CircleCi VS Jenkins

Tags: android, git, unit-testing, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm writing tests for my android project and since there are more than one developer on my team, we'd like the commits to **auto-build** when we push our code to Git so we are now thinking of integrating a CI system like **Travis** or **CircleCI**. Since there are more than one options available, I'd want to pick one that **builds and runs Test cases automatically** along-with building the main app so that the team members would be notified if a Test has failed and what changes they need to make in their code. I've tried Travis, its good , (with some headaches while configuring with github repo), i was wondering if any of you guys have tried the three in question here and suggest one for our purpose.

Comment: I've tried Travis and CircleCi, and found Travis to be better, every commit auto-builds. However it doesn't run tests i guess.

Comment: this question is offtopic and too broad, there is no "right" answer to this question, questions asking for suggestions out of the possible options won't get you any "right" answers, everyone has their preference when it comes to CI softwares, gradle itself handles most of what you are looking for in a CI like building, running unit tests and if integrated with jacoco you can also generate test coverage reports.

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for Stack Overflow. You might try [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 5):

There is a very good comparison made between these three in [this stackshare table](http://stackshare.io/stackups/travis-ci-vs-circleci-vs-jenkins).

It is community driven too, so it might be a good starting point to decide which one are you going to use.

**Travis CI:**

- Github integration
- Free for open source
- Easy to get started
- Nice interface
- Automatic deployment
- Tutorials for each programming language

**CircleCI**

- Github integration
- Fast builds
- Easy setup
- Competitively priced
- Slack integration
- Great customer support

**Jenkins**

- Hosted internally
- Free open source
- Great to build, deploy or launch anything async
- Rich set of plugins with good documentation
- Tons of integrations
- Has support for build pipelines

Comment: only now Travis lists slack integrations

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to throw in that Snap CI can also do this. Plus there's also stages to test things incrementally allowing for faster feedback.

Here's a post that brings a little more information to the table.

https://blog.snap-ci.com/blog/2014/07/22/why-snapci-and-travisci-are-not-the-same-thing/

Comment: Snap CI is no longer a thing according to this:
https://support.thoughtworks.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000283626-SnapCI-is-going-away